is there a better way to keep the focus on an Entry control besides using a timer?
I have an app that gets input from a HID barcode scanner where I need to always keep the focus on an Entry control.
I have it working using a timer but I would like a cleaner solution.
I read everything I can find on the Entry control but found no information on how I might do this.
This is what I have working.
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var KeepFocusTimer = Application.Current.Dispatcher.CreateTimer();
    KeepFocusTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    KeepFocusTimer.Tick += (s, e) => OnKeepFocusTimer();
    KeepFocusTimer.Start();
}


void OnKeepFocusTimer()
{
    MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        tx_BarCodeNumber.Focus();
    });
}


use the Unfocused event?

Don't let anything else receive focus. Or forward focus.

I researched Entry when I should have researched Events!
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.visualelement.unfocused?view=net-maui-8.0
This works!
Clean, Simple.
In the xaml add a handler
`Unfocused=" OnBarcodeNumberUnfocused "
private void OnBarcodeNumberUnfocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)}
{
tx_BarCodeNumber.Focus();
}`
Thanks Jason.
You gave me just enough info to figure this out.
